# NMOS common source amplifier with source resistance

Tags: mosfet, amplifier

I want to ask Is Vds is equal to Vd ? and What could be the conditions for Vds= Vgs. And what is difference between Vgs and vgs?

Answer (score 1):

V<sub>ds</sub> is not the same as V<sub>d</sub>. Rather, V<sub>ds</sub> = V<sub>d</sub> - V<sub>s</sub>.

V<sub>ds</sub> equal to V<sub>gs</sub> would imply the gate is connected to the drain, not an uncommon arrangement. It makes the transistor act something like a diode.

Typically, V<sub>gs</sub> would be used to represent the total DC+AC gate-source voltage, while v<sub>gs</sub> would represent the AC component of the gate-source voltage only.

Comment: and one more question. Is Vdd is equal to Vd?

Comment: That's a bit questionable really. In some cases, Vdd refers to the entire circuit's voltage supply, which may be different than the actual drain-to-ground voltage that Vd represents. But in other cases, they may refer to the same thing.

Comment: last one. If a source resistance is given how could we draw the pi-model? or we have to draw the T-model?

Comment: You just put a resistor in series with the source terminal of the model. That should work regardless of which model you use.

Comment: do you have a facebook account or whatsapp I have to ask some more questions in person if you don't mind.

Comment: I do not, though Stack Exchange does have chatrooms if you really need help.

Comment: I'm a new member and don't have permission to chat. Can you message me? in chat

Comment: difference between Av , Avo and Gv?

Comment: Oh, then I'm afraid that won't work. Even if I message you, you won't be able to reply. If you have further questions, you could ask them in a new question, though it's recommended you try to look up the answers yourself first.

Comment: If ro (r-not) is infinity, then I have to just neglect it while calculating gain?

Comment: If it's infinity, it's an open circuit. So yes, you can ignore it.

Comment: answer the question above diferrence between Av, Avo and Gv?

Comment: I honestly can't remember what those terms mean. It's been a very long time since I've dealt with small-signal modelling.

Comment: can you tell me about what role Rsig plays?

Comment: At this point I'm beginning to wonder if you've made any effort to search for these answers on your own. Have you tried going to google?

Comment: I have done some work. I just want to ask if there is a source resistance what would be the formula for overall voltage gain Gv and Loaded voltage gain Av?